# Is it possible to reuse grid pattern/template in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, grid

In my WPF application I'd like to reuse grid template few times. 
I defined a data template for grid (named GrdTemplate) and I would like to use this template in several places of my XAML definition.
How one can use grid template?

Here is my `XAML` code:

```
      <Grid Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ElementName=listboxItems, Path=ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=0.48}"
                      MaxWidth="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ElementName=listboxItems, Path=ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=0.1}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
                            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2" />
                        </Style>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="GrdTemplate">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Path=Tr}" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Path=Hr}" />
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  
                                                   Text="{Binding Path=TypeK}" />
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"  
                                               Text="{Binding Path=Tk}"  />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  
                                               Text="{Binding Path=Lft}" />
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  
                                               Text="{Binding Path=Crd}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                            Background="#FF576577"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" BorderThickness="2">
                        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" >

                            !!! Here I want to use my template with Object1 as Datasource !!!

                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                            Background="#FF576577"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" BorderThickness="2">
                        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" >

                            !!! Here I want to use my template with Object2 as Datasource !!!

                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should use here is not a `DataTemplate` but a `UserControl`. `DataTemplates` are typically used for controls that have a collection of child controls that you want to take the same appearance.

Then use your custom UserControl like this:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
<!--Here I want to use my template with Object2 as Datasource-->
    <views:MyGrdUserControl DataContext="{Binding Object2}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

If you do want to use your `DataTemplate` though you could use a `ContentPresenter` and set the `ContentTemplate` to be your GrdTemplate resource

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
<!--Here I want to use my template with Object2 as Datasource-->
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Object2}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GrdTemplate}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) is more *careful* with `DataTemplate` usage statement: *"DataTemplate objects are **particularly useful** when you are binding an ItemsControl such as a ListBox to an entire collection"*.